# SetVB6 ListBox Rowsource with Excel Range

Tags: excel, vb6

I am trying to set a VB6 Form ListBox with an Excel Range. I realize I can set the list using an array of the range, but I would like to use the Rowsource instead as it takes some of the formatting along if I do it as a Rowsource. There are 6 columns in the ListBox. I am getting a Run-time error '380',  Could not set the RowSource property. Invalied property value. Here's my code:

```
lastRow = wb.Sheets("Journal").Range("D20000").End(xlUp).Row
lstJrnl.RowSource = wb.Sheets("Journal").Range("D4:I" & lastRow).Address
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: The VB6 ListBox doesn't have this property.  What control are you actually using?  Probbly doesn't matter, since the DataList and DBList can't use a "range" as a RowSource.  Is this really VB6 or is it Excel VBA?

Comment: It a form hat was exported from VBA and imported to VB6 as a designer form. I guess I'll have to do the formatting manually. Thanks.